# Inactive relationships affecting measures

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling, powerbi-desktop

I have the following tables & relationships in our pbix report: 
[image]

For some obvious reasons, I need to have a relationship (non-active) between Dates[date] and Table2[T2Date]. However, doing so causes data fluctuation to measure 'Total Amount' in Table1.

Here are some screenshots: 
[image]

**Before Relationship (Dates[date] - Table2[T2Date]):**

[image]

**After Relationship (Dates[date] - Table2[T2Date]):**

[image]

I need to understand why this difference is coming up and how the relationship is causing it since the measure uses a different relationship.

For reference, I am attaching the pbix report.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XknisXvElS6uQN224bEcZ_biX7m-4el4

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link that @MikeHoney gives has really useful information on the subtleties of relationships and does relate to this problem (do watch it!), but this issue is not ultimately related to bidirectional filtering in particular. In fact, I can reproduce it with this simplified relationship structure:

[image: Relationship Diagram]

The key thing to note here is that when you attach `Table2` to `Dates`, since `Table2` contains `T2Date` values that don't match to any `Date[date]`, this creates an extra row in `Dates` with a blank date which you can notice in your filter on `6. Year` when that relationship exists (active or inactive). Filtering out that that blank in the `6. Year` filter would work, except that in your measure, you use `ALL(Dates)` to strip all filtering done on that table.

There are multiple ways to resolve this discrepancy, the easiest being replacing `ALL` with `ALLNOBLANKROW`. If you used `ALLSELECTED` that would also work in conjunction with filtering out blanks on your report-level filter on `6. Year`.

Cleaning up some items not relevant in this context and changing `ALL` to `ALLNOBLANKROW`, your total measure can be more simply written as:

```
ALLNOBLANKROW =
VAR EndServiceDate =
    MAX ( Dates[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Table1[Net Amount] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLNOBLANKROW ( Dates ),
            Dates[Date] <= EndServiceDate
        ),
        Table1[Flag2] = 1,
        Table1[Flag] = TRUE ()
    )
```

Results with no `6. Year` filter and with two measures, one using `ALL` and one using `ALLNOBLANKROW`:

[image: Comparison Table]

Notice that every row in the `ALL` column has been reduced by `-7,872.01`. This is the sum of all the `Net Amount` values that don't match to any dates in the `Dates` table. If you remove the relationship from `Dates[date]` to `Table2[T2Date]` then the blank row no longer exists and both of these will match the `ALLNOBLANKROW` version.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the Cross Filter Direction to **Both** on any relationship is a bit risky - you essentially hand over control of the runtime query designs to the Power BI robots. There's then a risk that they will come up with a "creative" query design that is unexpected.

There's some insight into how this happens in a recent talk by Alberto Ferrari:

https://www.sqlbi.com/tv/understanding-relationships-in-power-bi/

I'm sure you'll agree it's quite terrifying.

Looking at your info, I expect you can avoid those traps by changing the Cross Filter Direction to **Single**, for the relationship from **MonthYear** to **Dates**.