# Any reason not to use Bidirectional Cross Filter Direction in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

See Screenshot.
We are looking at the relationship between two tables, and there is a setting that effects how filtration works.
REF:  https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/cross-filtering/td-p/140592

For some reason, Both is not the default.
Any reason why you would not want it to be both?
[image: Bidirectional filtration]

Comment: This could be one of the reasons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55771337/inactive-relationships-affecting-measures

Comment: Last I did not used `Both` because I wanted my report to filter only on employee Id and not on department Id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bidirectional filters, it's easy to create ambiguous relationships and/or multiple filter paths between tables. They certainly have their uses but can introduce unnecessary complexity.

I'd encourage you to check out the discussion on this topic here:

[Is Bidirectional filtering really that bad?](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Is-Bidirectional-filtering-really-that-bad/td-p/695965)

This discussion also references the follwing SQL BI article by Alberto Ferrari:

[Bidirectional relationships and ambiguity in DAX](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/bidirectional-relationships-and-ambiguity-in-dax/)